# iOS Swift: Cannot Manipulate String: Value of type 'String' has no member 'firstIndex'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hi I am trying to manipulate a String, though the code from Apples developer Site does not work:

```
let name = "Marie Curie"
let firstSpace = name.firstIndex(of: " ") ?? name.endIndex
let firstName = name[..<firstSpace]
// firstName == "Marie"
```

You can find the example here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string

Seems like `firstIndex(of: " ")` does not exist any longer

I don't understand why this is not working is there a new func with a different name or what could be the problem? I am confused did Apple missed this one and nobody needed it so far???

Thanks a lot

There is a question that is similar though its answered with index(of: Character) though I am looking for something like index(of: String)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2997120-firstindex
Check your Xcode version

Comment: got version 9.4.1

Comment: See Carlos' answer for a fix along your original intention; if you only want to use this to get first/last name from a string you might also be interested in `name.split(separator: " ")` which returns `["Marie", "Curie"]`.

Comment: no actually its a little more complex, I could not do it that way, I just took this as an easy example

Answer (score 3):

it all depends on what version of swift you are using, the continuous improvement of the swift language , includes syntax changes

replace  `firstIndex(of:` to `.index(of:`

```
let name = "Marie Curie"
let firstSpace = name.index(of: " ") ?? name.endIndex
let firstName = name[..<firstSpace]
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that too but I am getting an error there "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Character" so seems like this is only available for Character and not for Strings

Comment: what version of xcode' and swift do you have in your project

Comment: Xcode: 9.4.1 and Swift: 4.1

Comment: Well there's your answer @SirJoe. You are looking at the docs for Xcode 10 but you are using Xcode 9.

Comment: ah okay, then what was the way you did it before that (I don't wanna download Xcode 10 if not necessary since its still in beta)

Answer (score 1):

```
let string = "Marie Curie"
let firstCharIndex = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let firstChar = string.substring(to: firstCharIndex)
print(firstChar)
```

Comment: the request is to search for a string this would not solve the problem in my case since the string I have to manipulate is unknown and could be anything I just know for sure that it contains some string sequence

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.